# Pairing, Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> I'd like to solve the following problem for part (ii). $X^*$ denotes the space of bounded linear functionals on the normed vector space $X$, and $\left<\ ,\right>$ stands for the pairing between a space and its dual. I desire to proceed with part (i); thus, I consider two cases separately. On the one hand, $x$ may come from $X\setminus \bar{Y}$. In this case, we use part (i) to find $x^*\in Y^\perp$ s.t. $||x^*||=1$ and $x^*(x)=\inf_{y\in Y}||x-y||$. But how does the absolute value of the pairing attain its maximum? On the other hand, $x$ may be included in the closure of $Y$.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case $x \not \in \overline{Y}$, you have found an $x_0^* \in Y^\perp$ such that $\inf_{y \in Y} \|x - y\| = x_0^*(x)$. If you can show that 
$$\sup_{x^* \in Y^\perp, \|x^*\| = 1} |\langle x, x^* \rangle | \leq \inf_{y \in Y} \|x - y\|$$
then it will follow that the $\sup$ is in fact a $\max$ which is attained at $x_0^*$. This is straightforward since for $x^* \in Y^\perp$ with $\|x^*\| = 1$ and $y \in Y$, 
$$|\langle x, x^* \rangle | = | \langle x - y, x^* \rangle | \leq \|x - y\|.$$
Since $y$ was arbitrary, taking the $\inf$ then gives the result.

It remains to deal with the case $x \in \overline{Y}$. In this case $\inf_{y \in Y} \|x - y\| = 0$. So we need to show that for $x^* \in Y^\perp$, $x^*(x) = 0$ also. To do this, pick a sequence $x_n$ in $Y$ such that $x_n \to x$. Then since $x^*$ is continuous,
$$x^*(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} x^*(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$$
as desired.

Comment: I have one more question.  Do you know how to prove $|| l ||=1$?

Comment: This is just immediate from the definition... $l( \lambda (x + Y)) = \lambda \|x + Y\|$.